# OpenSSL: Fetching SQL Server public certificate

Tags: sql-server, openssl, certificate

I want to use OpenSSL or any native Linux command to grab the certificate of a SQL Server. I tried the same way as I do with an HTTP server but it doesn't work.

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect MY.MSSQL.SERVER:1433
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 249 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

Comment: I think this will be difficult because 1433 allows for connection with and without ssl. So there must be a means by which TDS (the protocol behind)  "enables" SSL on a per connection basis. Which is something openssl does not do ... Perhaps you need to write a Java program which that connects using ssl and then extract the certificate ? (unless you decide to do it manually from the SQL Server admin panel)

Comment: see also https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/81681/26839

Comment: In my similar, but unrelated question  https://stackoverflow.com/q/58416600/12597, i go into detail on how to decode the WireShark network packet to get the certificate. Of course, this question is about OpenSSL, and not WireShark. And my question is about the client, and not OpenSSL or WireShark.

Answer (score 13):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/lnattrass/a4a91dbf439fc1719d69f7865c1b1791) by github user lnattrass gives a python script that is **"A terrible way to connect to MS SQL Server and dump the certificate as a PEM"** (his wording) in python. Yes, that's not what you asked about, you asked about OpenSSL. But one of the comments says in part

> I was able to get the same results using openssl like this: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <hostname>:<port> </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >dbcertfile.pem` as suggested somewhere.

*(no clue where "somewhere" would have been.)*

I've tried the openssl method but it failed for me:

```
rpresser@11MTLDEV-L11626:~$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect mysqlserver.mydomain.com:1433 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >dbcertfile.pem
unable to load certificate
140246796931520:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Perhaps this was because the self-signed cert (see below) was not trusted? I'm really not sure.

After fixing one indentation bug, the python method worked for me:

```
rpresser@11MTLDEV-L11626:/mnt/c/temp$ python3 get_tds_cert.py redacted.domain.COM 1433
# get_tdspacket: 0, tdspacket len: 43
# Header:  {'type': 4, 'status': 1, 'length': 43, 'channel': 0, 'packet': 1, 'window': 0}
# Remaining tdspbuf length: 0

# Starting TLS handshake loop..
# Shaking (0/5)

# get_tdspacket: 0, tdspacket len: 894
# Header:  {'type': 18, 'status': 1, 'length': 894, 'channel': 0, 'packet': 0, 'window': 0}
# Remaining tdspbuf length: 0

# Shaking (1/5)

# get_tdspacket: 0, tdspacket len: 67
# Header:  {'type': 18, 'status': 1, 'length': 67, 'channel': 0, 'packet': 0, 'window': 0}
# Remaining tdspbuf length: 0

# Handshake completed, dumping certificates
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I haven't bothered to redact the certificate because it is the [SQL Server self-signed fallback](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2007728/error-message-when-you-use-ssl-for-connections-to-sql-server-the-certi), as displayed by [SSLShopper Certificate Decoder](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html)

> - Certificate Information:
> - Common Name: SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback
> - Valid From: February 1, 2020
> - Valid To: February 1, 2050
>     Serial Number: 61cd18125c7f618145fd0d0f218113c4

Comment: There's actually two needed corrections, noted in the comments on GitHub: remove the indentation on line 62 and line 44 is to be moved inside the for loop below it. Lazy folks can just copy and paste from a [corrected fork](https://gist.github.com/Scherlac/0f048eb8f2aab274a903dcda5acbd99f).

Answer (score 4):

After looking for openssl solutions without sucesss and fighting with the python script without success too (both the initial and the fixed versions throwed an error) i resorted to use nmap, in this case it was quite easy:

```
nmap -v --script=ssl-cert -p 1433 server.example.com
```

In the output there should be a certificate such as this (selfsigned cert), you should be able to clean the formatting and use it where you need.

```
| SHA-1: dba1 14a3 d2c7 9410 0a7a bb8d d08e e1a0 d6a1 9e87
| -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
| MIIB+zCCAWSgAwIBAgIQJW6eoEmJJJJDqpOSmq2W6TANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADA7
| MTkwNwYDVQQDHjAAUwBTAEwAXwBTAGUAbABmAF8AUwBpAGcAbgBlAGQAXwBGAGEA
| bABsAGIAYQBjAGswIBcNMjMwMTE4MTEyOTQ5WhgPMjA1MzAxMTgxMTI5NDlaMDsx
| OTA3BgNVBAMeMABTAFMATABfAFMAZQBsAGYAXwBTAGkAZwBuAGUAZABfAEYAYQBs
| AGwAYgBhAGMAazCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAxKxXDgSq1++4
| yDSOmXDO5F2gDa1cW2x4USQOxXq5ux4RObhteo9pVOIDi2TfmKMUl9OTNUqfxiTl
| YJtHmBKP7aghWK5Z9p5VBDfbzmAG04tdII49piocKvdimy96veGWnPUGFdovx35k
| dEOT7+NpQTVIDscsIIDa8csQJmuwgdsCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOBgQBV
| 0KzioJl5tcvpjG2VK/TTpfAdZnz4MZwhg/ThviRtcV3WLVkKbCOh0A1ljCoURgsX
| HIvYXBHn1XdJn4F8HHeh8B53tjwRYkvxg2jGWfKofr0nAu23rbMv3543UroSH6r2
| 3CeLkgsAwFUcXPUfYwae5L48FKlkD5V2TsOhmy8rvg==
|_-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the https://gist.github.com/lnattrass/a4a91dbf439fc1719d69f7865c1b1791 with help from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/1ef08b76-1594-40cf-8ce0-d2407133dd3d

Similar [implementation](https://gist.github.com/MichaelNesterenko/c6906348a49bb3fcdd174584c53242a5) in groovy (java 11) which returns certificate chain from sql server:

```
groovy sqlserver-cert.groovy <host> <port>
```

Comment: The groovy script worked for me after commenting out the line with the `maximumPacketSize` setting. The Python script did not work for me.