# How can SQL Server client get information on TLS certificate being used?

Tags: sql-server, ssl, encryption, certificate, sql-server-2017

If a client connects to SQL Server, and a certificate is used to power TLS encryption, how can i get information about that certificate?

Ideally i want all the details, but i'd be happy with

- **Issuer:** `SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback`
- **Issued to:** `SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback`
- **SHA1 fingerprint:** `6640479c9cac2b7ca63c9708c71a9245b951b4c7`

Obviously i can't just look at the configuration on the server; as i'm trying to verify no MitM.

Also, i want to verify the correct certificate is being used (especially when no certificate is selected for use in the SQL Server Configuration Manager).

Either way: i want the client to be able to *verify* the certificate.

How can i get information about the certificate.

Assume:

- ADO.net *([**SqlClient** provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=netframework-4.8))*
- ADO  *([SQLOLEDB Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#targetText=The%20Microsoft%20OLE%20DB%20Provider,to%20access%20Microsoft%20SQL%20Server.&targetText=The%20Microsoft%20OLE%20DB%20Provider%20for%20SQL%20Server%20(SQLOLEDB)%20remains,it%20for%20new%20development%20work.))*
- OLEDB *([SQLOLEDB Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#targetText=The%20Microsoft%20OLE%20DB%20Provider,to%20access%20Microsoft%20SQL%20Server.&targetText=The%20Microsoft%20OLE%20DB%20Provider%20for%20SQL%20Server%20(SQLOLEDB)%20remains,it%20for%20new%20development%20work.))*

Whichever helps.

### Bonus - Decoding network traffic

You can spy on the network traffic, and view the raw TLS handshake:

```
16 03 01 04 d0 02 00 00 51 03 01 5d a7 35 91 e7 c2 8d f3 3e d5 e4 6d ec 9a b9 7f af c1 43 ad d3 51 41 b7 44 4f 57 4e 47 52 44 00 20 d1 03 00 00 5b 82 d8 85 fe e2 b6 9a 6c ec 88 69 fc ee d3 61
23 e4 ae 17 3b be 1a e2 8f 29 23 ca c0 14 00 00 09 00 17 00 00 ff 01 00 01 00 0b 00 03 08 00 03 05 00 03 02 30 82 02 fe 30 82 01 e6 a0 03 02 01 02 02 10 20 9e 8f 8c 08 72 c1 bf 45 ad f8 df 73
1f 21 47 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 0b 05 00 30 3b 31 39 30 37 06 03 55 04 03 1e 30 00 53 00 53 00 4c 00 5f 00 53 00 65 00 6c 00 66 00 5f 00 53 00 69 00 67 00 6e 00 65 00 64 00 5f 00
46 00 61 00 6c 00 6c 00 62 00 61 00 63 00 6b 30 1e 17 0d 31 39 31 30 31 36 31 34 30 31 30 36 5a 17 0d 34 39 31 30 31 36 31 34 30 31 30 36 5a 30 3b 31 39 30 37 06 03 55 04 03 1e 30 00 53 00 53
00 4c 00 5f 00 53 00 65 00 6c 00 66 00 5f 00 53 00 69 00 67 00 6e 00 65 00 64 00 5f 00 46 00 61 00 6c 00 6c 00 62 00 61 00 63 00 6b 30 82 01 22 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01 05 00 03
82 01 0f 00 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 b6 dc 05 25 3e 1e 41 82 f6 b4 bc 97 1c c5 1e 02 a6 bb 1a c7 34 ed 51 cc 65 a6 60 72 0c 3c 0e ac 57 df 4f df 18 15 14 6f e0 9c d4 39 36 a1 8e 5b 17 85 0a
93 c2 78 02 70 89 f5 35 18 55 37 14 b0 6e 4c cd 0d e7 a0 81 33 c8 42 bc 55 f6 71 fa 4e d2 98 5e 63 5b 32 a6 c3 04 21 3d 22 df 8c ee a7 6e 53 4b be 3d e6 39 c9 90 c6 a9 ed df 7a a8 46 83 b9 7c
f1 03 7c 45 b1 be 42 ee 71 aa bc d6 7b 27 41 f3 b8 c4 16 2a 18 8a 38 4c 19 51 25 78 56 ce 12 75 d0 eb 29 19 c5 70 b1 c0 13 18 77 77 a6 9b 47 1f fe 1f 27 5a 50 fb 3f 73 03 c3 a0 5d 2f f4 dd 37
fd df 87 f0 80 e9 de a7 16 df ee b8 00 c2 1e 68 49 19 ce 44 f4 af ac bf d3 5f b8 1c 64 d5 95 1f 8b 32 c1 5a 80 a8 21 2d 2c 66 b8 7e 29 13 11 f8 1f e1 e9 0f 68 4e 0a b8 1b 3c f3 28 6f b7 46 85
b1 17 c9 c6 82 e4 3c 28 d4 6d d9 5b dd 02 03 01 00 01 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 0b 05 00 03 82 01 01 00 3e f8 c8 54 30 c1 c1 12 5e eb 01 e5 50 41 57 55 de 9e 2e 69 2a 14 fa 9a 5a 9f
d3 c3 1c 28 49 28 b2 c2 e0 cf 3d 7f 48 88 3c 25 e3 30 b7 93 e1 5c a5 9c 6f 41 b0 fb 55 67 69 e5 c5 0e 46 7c e6 2b b4 2b d8 ac 42 62 1e 18 01 69 cd e0 85 59 77 19 bd f9 17 fc 1d 10 ba 8a 93 aa
88 8e e9 73 2c 56 2e d1 5e 22 ca 20 61 4c 03 f0 70 9f a7 a7 ed 16 3a fa 00 0e 9e 39 e8 6b 99 a1 72 cb 48 b8 88 26 2d 9d 3f d6 48 70 f0 a5 51 ee c0 a9 0a e8 cf e6 ed 27 79 4d f1 23 a6 f4 64 a0
72 04 2a 3a b9 30 aa 84 e4 d2 26 9d 8c 3e b5 fe 87 ef 2c 21 c7 4e 38 1f b7 b1 25 69 68 d8 42 b1 8d 25 f3 90 14 78 d2 39 9f 0f 17 2a fc 24 2e 3b 3b 40 99 c6 fb c9 0a b0 af cd 66 f1 c9 84 c5 be
dc e9 38 bb 36 2d be 6b db db 86 95 96 c6 84 4b 7d b0 a1 ea f7 42 b2 56 93 ec e9 fd 86 8f a5 ad f0 57 63 78 d0 5a 0c 00 01 67 03 00 18 61 04 6d f6 56 8c e9 8a 82 29 0a d4 da ea be 89 52 30 bf
cd 49 66 77 7f 18 12 b1 75 44 96 d1 9e 6d 15 da 69 ba a7 7c ee 6f ab 96 ea b0 0d 64 0f c4 22 ba d7 9f 54 71 15 42 84 50 95 a4 ad 16 15 71 56 a7 0a 80 60 2d 83 86 80 0a 96 7b 30 6a aa b7 be 8f
45 9b 96 1a 5c b2 d3 e6 28 6f c4 e4 bb 70 ce 01 00 23 e6 8d 9e bf fc 90 66 f8 07 b6 6b 44 bb 03 b5 3b fd 72 fe 7b 5a e6 15 5d 10 d6 51 22 b8 44 8d 27 85 20 53 04 fb 06 32 b7 03 9e ba 7a 32 62
f1 61 25 8a c4 42 3a 02 1f be cf 92 4d 6e 48 d3 48 8b 8f 03 dc 66 d8 8b 63 21 be 6f b0 53 1c 00 37 4e 7e 4f e8 1e ba d2 c4 45 0f c0 13 ed 71 ee 47 f3 4c 0d 1d af d5 d5 bb 52 78 4b b3 55 70 4e
bc a4 f1 da 4a ec 60 7a af 81 23 49 16 57 db 8e 8b 22 65 91 3f 5b 1c 0a 13 d0 e4 b0 a4 d3 10 33 a3 bd c9 39 b6 ea 9b 73 67 11 49 ed 4f 6d 71 ae ce a3 2a 3a 6d 07 d9 d6 24 89 27 2d e6 5a e9 e1
e0 6c 47 5c c1 c0 72 01 e6 63 a6 06 7f 0d b0 16 68 7d 82 49 86 df 38 9b b4 95 5a 95 f8 e8 03 e9 63 83 7c c4 07 62 a1 f5 ce 48 0a 0c 6e 9c da e5 bf 5e e4 56 a1 de 98 80 e5 65 df eb 25 7c 38 97
8a e1 8d a3 c9 a8 a6 f8 bb 77 06 16 ec 21 8a 5c 0e 0e 00 00 00
```

Which can then be decoded:

**Record Header**

```
16              ; type 0x16 (22) = Handshake record
03 01           ; protocol version { 3, 1 } TLS 1.0
04 d0           ; 0x04d0 bytes of handshake message follows
```

**Handshake**

```
02                       ; Handshake type 0x02 (2=server_hello)
00 51                    ; bytes in message 0x0051 (88-bytes)
03 01                    ; server_version { 3, 1 } (TLS 1.0)
5d a7 35 91              ; random.gmt_unix_time (1571239313 = 10/16/2019 3:21pm UTC)
e7 c2 8d f3 3e d5 e4 6d  ; random.random_bytes 28-bytes 
ec 9a b9 7f af c1 43 ad  
d3 51 41 b7 44 4f 57 4e 
47 52 44 00 20 d1 03 00  ; "çÂ.ó>Õämìš¹¯ÁC­ÓQA·DOWNGRD\0"

00 5b 82 d8 85 fe e2 b6  ; SessionID (variable length 2..32-bytes)
9a 6c ec 88 69 fc ee d3 
61 23 e4 ae 17 3b be 1a 
e2 8f 29 23 ca c0 14 00 

00 09                    ; CipherSuite { 0, 9} (TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA)
00 17                    ; CipherSuite { 0, 0x17 } = (TLS_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5)
00 00                    ; CipherSuite { 0, 0 } (TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL)

ff                       ; compression_method 0xff
01                       ; compression_method 0x01
00                       ; compression_method 0x00 (0=null)

01 00                    ; ???
```

**Handshake header**

```
0b          ; 0x0b (11) handshake message (11=certificate)
00 03 08    ; 0x308 (776) bytes of certificates to follow
```

**Certificates length**

```
00 03 05    ; length of all certificates to follow is 0x305 (773) bytes
```

**Certificate 1 Length**

```
00 03 02    ; certificate 1 length 0x302 (770) bytes
```

**Certificate 1**

```
30 82 02 fe 30 82 01 e6 a0 03 02 01 02 02 10 20 9e 8f 8c 08 72 c1 bf 45 ad f8 df 73 1f 21 47 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 0b 05 00 30 3b 31 39 30 37 06 03 55 04 03 1e 30 00
53 00 53 00 4c 00 5f 00 53 00 65 00 6c 00 66 00 5f 00 53 00 69 00 67 00 6e 00 65 00 64 00 5f 00 46 00 61 00 6c 00 6c 00 62 00 61 00 63 00 6b 30 1e 17 0d 31 39 31 30 31 36 31 34 30 31 30 36 5a
17 0d 34 39 31 30 31 36 31 34 30 31 30 36 5a 30 3b 31 39 30 37 06 03 55 04 03 1e 30 00 53 00 53 00 4c 00 5f 00 53 00 65 00 6c 00 66 00 5f 00 53 00 69 00 67 00 6e 00 65 00 64 00 5f 00 46 00 61
00 6c 00 6c 00 62 00 61 00 63 00 6b 30 82 01 22 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01 05 00 03 82 01 0f 00 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 b6 dc 05 25 3e 1e 41 82 f6 b4 bc 97 1c c5 1e 02 a6 bb 1a
c7 34 ed 51 cc 65 a6 60 72 0c 3c 0e ac 57 df 4f df 18 15 14 6f e0 9c d4 39 36 a1 8e 5b 17 85 0a 93 c2 78 02 70 89 f5 35 18 55 37 14 b0 6e 4c cd 0d e7 a0 81 33 c8 42 bc 55 f6 71 fa 4e d2 98 5e
63 5b 32 a6 c3 04 21 3d 22 df 8c ee a7 6e 53 4b be 3d e6 39 c9 90 c6 a9 ed df 7a a8 46 83 b9 7c f1 03 7c 45 b1 be 42 ee 71 aa bc d6 7b 27 41 f3 b8 c4 16 2a 18 8a 38 4c 19 51 25 78 56 ce 12 75
d0 eb 29 19 c5 70 b1 c0 13 18 77 77 a6 9b 47 1f fe 1f 27 5a 50 fb 3f 73 03 c3 a0 5d 2f f4 dd 37 fd df 87 f0 80 e9 de a7 16 df ee b8 00 c2 1e 68 49 19 ce 44 f4 af ac bf d3 5f b8 1c 64 d5 95 1f
8b 32 c1 5a 80 a8 21 2d 2c 66 b8 7e 29 13 11 f8 1f e1 e9 0f 68 4e 0a b8 1b 3c f3 28 6f b7 46 85 b1 17 c9 c6 82 e4 3c 28 d4 6d d9 5b dd 02 03 01 00 01 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 0b 05
00 03 82 01 01 00 3e f8 c8 54 30 c1 c1 12 5e eb 01 e5 50 41 57 55 de 9e 2e 69 2a 14 fa 9a 5a 9f d3 c3 1c 28 49 28 b2 c2 e0 cf 3d 7f 48 88 3c 25 e3 30 b7 93 e1 5c a5 9c 6f 41 b0 fb 55 67 69 e5
c5 0e 46 7c e6 2b b4 2b d8 ac 42 62 1e 18 01 69 cd e0 85 59 77 19 bd f9 17 fc 1d 10 ba 8a 93 aa 88 8e e9 73 2c 56 2e d1 5e 22 ca 20 61 4c 03 f0 70 9f a7 a7 ed 16 3a fa 00 0e 9e 39 e8 6b 99 a1
72 cb 48 b8 88 26 2d 9d 3f d6 48 70 f0 a5 51 ee c0 a9 0a e8 cf e6 ed 27 79 4d f1 23 a6 f4 64 a0 72 04 2a 3a b9 30 aa 84 e4 d2 26 9d 8c 3e b5 fe 87 ef 2c 21 c7 4e 38 1f b7 b1 25 69 68 d8 42 b1
8d 25 f3 90 14 78 d2 39 9f 0f 17 2a fc 24 2e 3b 3b 40 99 c6 fb c9 0a b0 af cd 66 f1 c9 84 c5 be dc e9 38 bb 36 2d be 6b db db 86 95 96 c6 84 4b 7d b0 a1 ea f7 42 b2 56 93 ec e9 fd 86 8f a5 ad
f0 57 63 78 d0 5a 0c 00 01 67 03 00 18 61 04 6d f6 56 8c e9 8a 82 29 0a d4 da ea be 89 52 30 bf cd 49 66 77 7f 18 12 b1 75 44 96 d1 9e 6d 15 da 69 ba a7 7c ee 6f ab 96 ea b0 0d 64 0f c4 22 ba
d7 9f 54 71 15 42 84 50 95 a4 ad 16 15 71 56 a7 0a 80 60 2d 83 86 80 0a 96 7b 30 6a aa b7 be 8f 45 9b 96 1a 5c b2 d3 e6 28 6f c4 e4 bb 70 ce 01 00 23 e6 8d 9e bf fc 90 66 f8 07 b6 6b 44 bb 03
b5 3b fd 72 fe 7b 5a e6 15 5d 10 d6 51 22 b8 44 8d 27 85 20 53 04 fb 06 32 b7 03 9e ba 7a 32 62 f1 61 25 8a c4 42 3a 02 1f be cf 92 4d 6e 48 d3 48 8b 8f 03 dc 66 d8 8b 63 21 be 6f b0 53 1c 00
37 4e 7e 4f e8 1e ba d2 c4 45 0f c0 13 ed 71 ee 47 f3 4c 0d 1d af d5 d5 bb 52 78 4b b3 55 70 4e bc a4 f1 da 4a ec 60 7a af 81 23 49 16 57 db 8e 8b 22 65 91 3f 5b 1c 0a 13 d0 e4 b0 a4 d3 10 33
a3 bd c9 39 b6 ea 9b 73 67 11 49 ed 4f 6d 71 ae ce a3 2a 3a 6d 07 d9 d6 24 89 27 2d e6 5a e9 e1 e0 6c 47 5c c1 c0 72 01 e6 63 a6 06 7f 0d b0 16 68 7d 82 49 86 df 38 9b b4 95 5a 95 f8 e8 03 e9
63 83 7c c4 07 62 a1 f5 ce 48 0a 0c 6e 9c da e5 bf 5e e4 56 a1 de 98 80 e5 65 df eb 25 7c 38 97 8a e1 8d a3 c9 a8 a6 f8 bb 77 06 16 ec 21 8a 5c 0e 0e 00 00 00
```

The certificate can then be [decoded](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIIC_jCCAeagAwIBAgIQIJ6PjAhywb9Frfjfcx8hRzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA7MTkwNwYDVQQDHjAAUwBTAEwAXwBTAGUAbABmAF8AUwBpAGcAbgBlAGQAXwBGAGEAbABsAGIAYQBjAGswHhcNMTkxMDE2MTQwMTA2WhcNNDkxMDE2MTQwMTA2WjA7MTkwNwYDVQQDHjAAUwBTAEwAXwBTAGUAbABmAF8AUwBpAGcAbgBlAGQAXwBGAGEAbABsAGIAYQBjAGswggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQC23AUlPh5Bgva0vJccxR4CprsaxzTtUcxlpmByDDwOrFffT98YFRRv4JzUOTahjlsXhQqTwngCcIn1NRhVNxSwbkzNDeeggTPIQrxV9nH6TtKYXmNbMqbDBCE9It-M7qduU0u-PeY5yZDGqe3feqhGg7l88QN8RbG-Qu5xqrzWeydB87jEFioYijhMGVEleFbOEnXQ6ykZxXCxwBMYd3emm0cf_h8nWlD7P3MDw6BdL_TdN_3fh_CA6d6nFt_uuADCHmhJGc5E9K-sv9NfuBxk1ZUfizLBWoCoIS0sZrh-KRMR-B_h6Q9oTgq4GzzzKG-3RoWxF8nGguQ8KNRt2VvdAgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAD74yFQwwcESXusB5VBBV1Xeni5pKhT6mlqf08McKEkossLgzz1_SIg8JeMwt5PhXKWcb0Gw-1VnaeXFDkZ85iu0K9isQmIeGAFpzeCFWXcZvfkX_B0QuoqTqoiO6XMsVi7RXiLKIGFMA_Bwn6en7RY6-gAOnjnoa5mhcstIuIgmLZ0_1khw8KVR7sCpCujP5u0neU3xI6b0ZKByBCo6uTCqhOTSJp2MPrX-h-8sIcdOOB-3sSVpaNhCsY0l85AUeNI5nw8XKvwkLjs7QJnG-8kKsK_NZvHJhMW-3Ok4uzYtvmvb24aVlsaES32woer3QrJWk-zp_YaPpa3wV2N40Fo):

- **Issued by**: `SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback`
- **Issued to**: `SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback`
- **Valid from**: `2019-10-16 14:01:06 UTC`
- **Valid to**:  `2049-10-16 14:01:06 UTC`
- **SHA1 fingerprint:** `6640479c9cac2b7ca63c9708c71a9245b951b4c7`

Of course that requires a network spying tool, and a lot of work.

As opposed to most of TLS clients (e.g. http, smtp, pop3, ftp, **[InternetQueryOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetqueryoptiona)**) allow you to view the client certificate directly:

[image]

## Bonus Chatter - The TLS Nonce Easter Egg

The random 28-byte NONCE, generated by SQL Server and sent to the client, contains an easter-egg (of sorts):

```
; random.random_bytes 28-bytes 
e7 c2 8d f3 3e d5 e4 6d ec 9a b9 7f af c1    çÂ.ó>Õämìš¹.¯Á
43 ad d3 51 41 b7 44 4f 57 4e 47 52 44 00    C.ÓQA·DOWNGRD.
```

It ends with "*`DOWNGRD\0`*".

That's a feature of TLS 1.3 designed to help a client detect a *downgrade attack*.

If the server is *capable* of supporting TLS 1.3, but it has been asked by the client to use something lower, it adds "DOWNGRD" to the random nonce:

- **`DOWNGRD\0`**: If the server was asked to negotiate TLS 1.1 or earlier
- **`DOWNGRD\1`**: If the server was asked to negotiate TLS 1.2

This way the client can detect if a *man-in-the-middle* intercepted the client, and altered the list of protocols supposedly supported by the client to trick the client into using TLS 1.2 (weaker), or TLS 1.1 or earlier (broken).

## Bonus Reading

- [How does TLS 1.3 protect against downgrade attacks?](https://blog.gypsyengineer.com/en/security/how-does-tls-1-3-protect-against-downgrade-attacks.html)
- [OpenSSL: Fetching SQL Server public certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34981859/12597) *(asking about OpenSSL)*
- [How can client retrieve SQL Server public SSL certificate?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/how-can-client-retrieve-sql-server-public-ssl-certificate) *(Asking for anything; including network sniffing)*

p.s. And, of course, this question does **not** belong on dba.stackexchange.com because this is a *programming* question (e.g. ADO.net, OLEDB), and not a DBA question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60084223/864696 links to a gist that has python code that works.